# HDFS file compression internally

Tags: hadoop, compression, hdfs

I am looking for a default compression in HDFS. I saw [this](http://comphadoop.weebly.com/) but I don' t want my files to have gzip like extensions(in fact, they should be accesible as if they didn' t compressed) Actually, what I am looking for is exactly like the option "*Compress contents to save disk space*" on Windows. This option compresses the files internally, but they can be accessed just like usual files. Any ideas will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exist in standard HDFS implementations and you have to manage it yourself. You have to manage your own compression. However, [a proprietary implementation of Hadoop, MapR, does this,](http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Compression) if solving this problem is important enough for you.

After using hadoop for a little while this doesn't really bother me anymore. Pig and MapReduce and such handle the compression automatically enough for me. I know that's not a real answer, but I couldn't tell in your question if you are simply annoyed or you have a real problem this is causing. Getting use to adding `| gunzip` to everything didn't take long. I For example:

- `hadoop fs -cat /my/file.gz | gunzip`
- `cat file.txt | gzip | hadoop fs -put - /my/file.txt.gz`

Answer (score 1):

When you're using compressed files you need to think about having them splittable - i.e. can Hadoop split this file when running a map reduce (if the file is not splittable it will only be read by a single map)

The usual way around this is to use a container format e.g. sequence file, orc file etc. where you can enable compression. If you are using simple text files (csv etc) - there's an [lzo project by twitter](https://github.com/kevinweil/hadoop-lzo) but I didn't use it personally

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to store files with compression in HDFS is through default compression argument while writing any file into HDFS. This is available in mapper libraries, sqoop, flume , hive , hbase catalog and so on. I am quoting some examples here from Hadoop. Here you dont need to worry about compressing the file locally for efficiency in hadoop. Its best to default hdfs file format option to perform this work. This type of compression will smoothly integrate with the hadoop mapper processing.

**Job written through Mapper Library**

While creating the writer in your mapper program. Here is the definition. You will write your own mapper and reducer to write the file into HDFS with your codec defined as a argument to the Writer method.

```
createWriter(Configuration conf, FSDataOutputStream out, Class keyClass, Class valClass, org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.CompressionType **compressionType**, CompressionCodec codec)
```

**Sqoop Import**

Below option send default compression argument for the file import into HDFS

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc://mysql://yourconnection/rawdata --table loglines --target-dir /tmp/data/logs/ --compress
```

with sqoop you can also specify specific codec as well with option

```
sqoop --connect jdbc://mysql://yourconnection/rawdata --table loglines --target-dir /tmp/data/logs compression-codec org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec
```

**Hive import**

Below example, you can use your desired option to read the file into hive. This again is property you can set while reading from your local file.

```
SET hive.exec.compress.output=true;
SET parquet.compression=**SNAPPY**; --this is the default actually
CREATE TABLE raw (line STRING) STORED AS PARQUET ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/tmp/weblogs/20090603-access.log' INTO TABLE raw;
```

I have not mentioned all the example of methods of data compression while you import into HDFS.

HDFS CLI doesn't (for e.g hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal) provide any direct way to compress. This is my understanding of working with hadoop CLI.